# How to show what the function does in documentation popup in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I saw on youtube video that vs code shows what the function does when you hover over. For example,

[image]

but when I do this it shows the parameter documentation only.
How do I achieve this in my vs code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a docstring. You can check the docs [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/).

To get it shown you must have the Python official extension installed in your VSCode and the comment in the implementation of the method.

Here is an example:

```
def func():
    """ my docs"""
```

You must install this extension:

Name: Python
Id: ms-python.python
Description: Linting, Debugging (multi-threaded, remote), Intellisense, Jupyter Notebooks, code formatting, refactoring, unit tests, and more.
Version: 2021.2.633441544
Publisher: Microsoft
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

Comment: I have a supplementary question: I have the Python extension installed; it works well for the standard Python library.

But it does not show anything for my own imported files.

How do I get it to display the doc from my own files as well?